# Catch size of incoming image and change parent's wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, state, rendering

I try to catch image's size and control it. For example I got image 80*100 size and I have to increase it and set this size to image's wrapper.

I use layoutEffect and useState but after render state doesn’t write real size. In currentRef it has sizes but in state - nope. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57etY.png)

How to correctly check and control size?

```
  const targetRef = useRef<HTMLImageElement | null>(null);

  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState<{
    width: number;
    height: number;
  }>({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (targetRef.current) {
      setDimensions({
        width: targetRef.current.offsetWidth,
        height: targetRef.current.offsetHeight,
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: instead of setting dimensions in `useLayoutEffect` you can try it inside the onLoad event of the image. Ref: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/re247.html

Comment: You can declare your image like `<img src="your_image_url" onload={onImageLoad} />` and you can copy paste the same thing which is present inside `useLayoutEffect` inside the `onImageLoad` function